# Ruby Regex Error: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I'm getting two errors, both revolving around encoding and both related.

The first error (technically, a warning) I get when starting up WEBrick:

```
/Users/USERNAME/example/config/initializers/bb-ruby.rb:54: warning: invalid Unicode Property \P: /\:\-?\P/
```

The line it's referring to is: `/\:\-?\P/,`

It's just a bit of regex, ultimately part of this block:

```
@@tags['Razzing'] = [
  /\:\-?\P/,
  '<img src="/assets/emoticons/razzing.png">',
  'Razzing',
  ':P',
  :razzing]
```

Then, I also get the following error when parsing some strings (presumably due to this same line)...

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError
incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
```

I'm running Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.1.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your Regex is being "compiled" as ASCII-8BIT.

Just add the encoding declaration at the top of the file where the Regex is declared:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

And you're done. Now, when Ruby is parsing your code, it will assume every literal you use (Regex, String, etc) is specified in UTF-8 encoding.

**UPDATE:** `UTF-8` is now the default encoding for Ruby 2.0 and beyond.

Comment: That stopped the `Encoding::CompatibilityError` error, but I'm still getting the `invalid Unicode Property` warning when starting up Webrick.

Comment: The Regex engine changed on Ruby 1.9… I don't know what you meant by `\P` originally, but now it is used to match Unicode code points, and it requires a parameter (like `\P{L}`, to match any non-letter character). See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: I'm trying to match this: `:-P` or `:P` (as in emoticon sticking tongue out)...how would I do that now?

Comment: omit the backslash before the P

Comment: Actually, you don't need any backslash on your expression. Remember, it's only used to escape characters that have a meaning for the Regex, such as: `(`, `[`, `{` (and their closing counterparts), `^`, `$` and `\ ` itself.

Comment: regex_string = ... read from json file ... # sample value: "^MatchPod/"
regex = Regexp.new(regex_string)

Any idea how to deal with this in my case? Will adding declaration in my case fix the issue too?

Comment: @knagode I'd recommend you open a new, well-written question for your case. It's very hard to help in the comments section.

Answer (score 5):

[Ruby 2.0 Document](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Encoding.html)

```
/Pattern/u - stand for UTF-8
```