# Rails: how to debug assets:precompile failure on cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm getting a cryptic error on `cap deploy`

```
$ cap deploy
. . .
  * executing "cd -- /rails/myapp/releases/20130919002235 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
    servers: ["persephone"]
    [persephone] executing command
. . .
 ** [out :: persephone] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: persephone] Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '["ok","(function() {': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
 ** [out :: persephone] (in /rails/myapp/releases/20130919002235/app/assets/javascripts/disk_files.js.coffee)
 ** [out :: persephone] /rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:242:in `rescue in parse_string'
 ** [out :: persephone] /rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:213:in `parse_string'
 ** [out :: persephone] /rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:257:in `parse_value'
 ** [out :: persephone] /rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:121:in `parse'
 ** [out :: persephone] /rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
. . .
```

In trying to debug the problem I've tried completely removing `disk_files.js.coffee` and then the same error occurs for `application.js`.

I've then changed my `application.js` manifest so that it doesn't require anything and then I get a similar error for `application.css`

I've commented out my custom css and now I get:

```
 ** [out :: persephone] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: persephone] undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 ** [out :: persephone] (in /rails/myapp/releases/20130919200133/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
 ** [out :: persephone] /rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:63:in `sprockets_context'
```

Each of these steps requires a git commit to origin and then a `cap deploy`.

FWIW- adding #encoding: UTF-8 as per [SO#9857443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857443/ruby-regex-error-incompatible-encoding-regexp-match-ascii-8bit-regexp-with-utf) doesn't help.

Anyone know what's going on? How can I debug this?

Comment: You can debug locally by looking like the production environment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: did you find out what is doing this? I am having a similar issue, where i used a stub command in my application.css ***= stub development/development_only** which is breaking precompile