# AWS Elastic Beanstalk crashing as soon as I do git aws:push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Having been able to provision a working AWS Elastic Beanstalk server from my mac osx local machine, i'm having a recurring problem with getting any app code to work. I initially tried with more ambitious, developed, apps using PG but now i have scaled all the way back to the most simple ["hello world" example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html). In every case, it seem to be related to a "spawning error". Presumably this is a problem with my local setup, but I'm having a hard time finding out where the problem is... here is an example of the EBS logs it'm getting back...

```
  [ 2014-10-02 16:19:54.5141 8472/7fe0be1c7700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is da12351c. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 8541 stdout: 
App 8541 stdout: 
[ 2014-10-02 16:22:03.8572 8472/7fe0c04d2700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/app/current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 5e8a831e
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-Cdt4kP.html
  Message from application: Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '[{"content-type":"ap': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string) (JSON::ParserError)
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:242:in `rescue in parse_string'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:213:in `parse_string'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:257:in `parse_value'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:121:in `parse'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:334:in `load'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:210:in `load_from_json'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:61:in `block in load_json'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:60:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:60:in `load_json'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types/loader.rb:87:in `load'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types.rb:280:in `load_default_mime_types'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types.rb:307:in `<class:Types>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mime-types-2.3/lib/mime/types.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail.rb:9:in `<module:Mail>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb:50:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/share/ruby/1.9/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
  /var/app/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/share/gems1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.53/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'


[ 2014-10-02 16:22:03.8710 8472/7fe0be1c7700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 5e8a831e. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.




/var/log/cfn-hup.log

2014-10-02 15:40:06,110 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2014-10-02 15:40:06,148 [DEBUG] SQS client initialized with endpoint https://queue.amazonaws.com
2014-10-02 15:40:06,148 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
2014-10-02 15:40:06,148 [DEBUG] Creating /var/lib/cfn-hup/data
2014-10-02 15:40:07,119 [INFO] Refreshing listener credentials
2014-10-02 15:40:07,333 [INFO] Scheduling next credential refresh in 7200 seconds
2014-10-02 15:43:18,912 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: 80c08848-3f80-435c-8a3a-c34efd1dda99)
2014-10-02 15:43:18,912 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2014-10-02 15:43:23,646 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2014-10-02 15:43:31,026 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: ce0442fa-e827-4668-8a8f-3859d49a1924)
2014-10-02 15:43:31,027 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2014-10-02 15:43:33,629 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2014-10-02 15:45:11,439 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 15:50:12,828 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 15:54:53,425 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: 771cc7ce-0d30-4a9f-9eda-a87c7dbd838e)
2014-10-02 15:54:53,425 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2014-10-02 15:54:57,335 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2014-10-02 15:55:13,547 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 15:59:30,065 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: c2795b8d-2361-4123-9080-9371b999d7a9)
2014-10-02 15:59:30,065 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2014-10-02 16:00:20,364 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 16:00:41,586 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2014-10-02 16:02:37,639 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: 7b441958-0b0b-424b-bc13-d4168db7abaa)
2014-10-02 16:02:37,639 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2014-10-02 16:02:40,061 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2014-10-02 16:05:38,625 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 16:07:26,078 [ERROR] InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 156, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 228, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
2014-10-02 16:07:32,098 [ERROR] InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 156, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 228, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
2014-10-02 16:07:39,618 [ERROR] InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 156, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 228, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
2014-10-02 16:07:51,683 [ERROR] InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 156, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 228, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
2014-10-02 16:10:28,535 [ERROR] InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 156, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 228, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
2014-10-02 16:10:34,142 [ERROR] InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 156, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 228, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
2014-10-02 16:10:41,074 [ERROR] InternalError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 156, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 228, in _timeout
    raise exc[0]
HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error
2014-10-02 16:11:02,932 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 16:16:04,324 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 16:18:08,898 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: dabadbe9-34c9-43be-8328-20a981f41240)
2014-10-02 16:18:08,899 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
2014-10-02 16:19:48,800 [INFO] Action for aws-eb-command-handler succeeded, returning SUCCESS
2014-10-02 16:20:09,030 [INFO] Already ran arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:391948720029:dispatcher/awseb-e-h74tvdcemu-stack/a038d89e-624e-4a8b-9340-528a8c27779b|ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup|dabadbe9-34c9-43be-8328-20a981f41240, deleting
2014-10-02 16:21:09,405 [INFO] command processing is alive.
2014-10-02 16:22:53,777 [INFO] Received command ElasticBeanstalkCommand-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup (invocation id: b5002f19-e1f7-4b5c-9985-e02673b18a8e)
2014-10-02 16:22:53,777 [INFO] Running action for aws-eb-command-handler
```

Comment: Are these all the logs? It looks like [passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger) is the point of failure in this case. How are you using it?

Comment: These aren't the complete logs - just the error parts. That said, I tried switching to passenger because the default was giving the same 'spawning' error. So I'm not sure that passenger is the problem... If it'll help I'll run the default setup instructions and post the full logs up for those when I get back to my machine.

Comment: For the incompatible encoding error can you try following the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9857493/161628
Adding "# encoding: utf-8" to config.ru
Also for the internal server, I am thinking it could be an intermittent issue. Is the internal server error repeatable for you?