# Replacing non standard characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have an array of strings:

```
strings = ["\u2014 some text", "\u00A0 Foo", "Bar"]
```

What statement should I write in order to get an array that looks like this:

```
strings = [" some text", " Foo", "Bar"]
```

I tried following, but no luck:

```
strings.map!{|string| string.gsub!(/(Wu2014|Wu00A0)/, '')}
```

Comment: Could you define "non standard", which characters should be kept / removed?

Comment: I want to remove all those Unicode characters like "\u2014", "\u00A0" etc.

Comment: Can you be more specific? "B" is also a Unicode character, so do you want to remove it as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove non-ASCII chars, then

```
strings.map{| s | s.encode('ASCII', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')}
```

Comment: This will remove non-ASCII from everywhere in the string. I have an impression thet must only be removed from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing one of the bangs. If you're looking to remove all non ASCII characters, you might try:

```
strings.map!{|string| string.gsub(/\P{ASCII}/,'')}
```

This will replace all non-ASCII characters with nothing.  For me, this results in:

```
[" some text", " Foo", "Bar"]
```

Comment: This seems to work, could you please tell me how do I match UTF-8 please?

Comment: This will actually remove all non-ASCII from the string - is it expected?

Comment: I have checked encoding of the string, and it returns UTF-8

Comment: I tried your solution and it throws an exception Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (IBM437 regexp with UTF-8 string)

Comment: I didn't know about `\P` (vs `\p`). Good to know. `/[^[[:ascii:]]]/` also works.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to remove all non-ASCII characters from the start of the string:

```
strings = ["\u2014 some text", "\u00A0 Foo", "Bar"]
strings.map!{|s| s.sub(/\A\P{ASCII}+/,'')} # remove non-ASCII from the start of the string
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/Q3j3Cv)

Or, you may remove all chars other than word and whitespace chars with

```
strings.map!{|s| s.sub(/\A[^\w\s]+/,'')}
```

See [this Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/ZavaL1).

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `\P{ASCII}` - any char but ASCII
- `[^\w\s]` - any character but a word (`\w`) or whitespace (`\s`) char
- `+` - a quantifier matching one or more occurrences of the quanitified pattern.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, but I am getting an exception: Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (IBM437 regexp with UTF-8 string)

Comment: What is the Ruby version you are using? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857443/ruby-regex-error-incompatible-encoding-regexp-match-ascii-8bit-regexp-with-utf

Comment: Sorry to hear the date is under the weather.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Could you explain what *the date is under the weather* means?

Comment: If you're familiar with the expression [under the weather](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=under%20the%20weather) it should be obvious. btw, the origin of that expression (scroll down at the link) is interesting.

Comment: OK, Wiktor, you've misspelled "details". :-)

Comment: I would have never spotted that, I typed in complete darkness and my eyes were sore. Thanks, now I got the pun.

Answer (score -1):

You have too many bangs and an incorrect regexp

Try either

```
strings.map{|string| string.gsub!(/(\u2014|\u00A0)/, '')}
```

or

```
strings.map!{|string| string.gsub(/(\u2014|\u00A0)/, '')}
```

or

```
new_strings = strings.map{|string| string.gsub(/(\u2014|\u00A0)/, '')}
strings = new_strings
```

Comment: well, for some reason, regex does not return matched pattern... so non of your solutions works.