# How do I make my Ruby regEx compile to the same encoding as the variable to which it is being applied?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding

Please note that this answer — [Ruby Regex Error: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857443/ruby-regex-error-incompatible-encoding-regexp-match-ascii-8bit-regexp-with-utf), doesn’t apply as I’m already using Ruby > 1.9.

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with Ruby 2.3.  I have this expression

```
phrase = phrase.gsub(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '')
```

Unfortunately, this dies with the below error if the encoding of the variable “phrase” is “ASCII-8BIT”.  Is there any way to write the above in an encoding that matches the encoding of the variable, phrase?  As I understand it, the regular expressions get automatically compiled as UTF-8, even though my variable may not be UTF-8.

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:449:in `gsub'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:449:in `find_header'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:157:in `block in get_headers_by_line'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/each.rb:7:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/each.rb:7:in `each_with_time_with_zone'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:156:in `get_headers_by_line'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:99:in `get_headers'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:243:in `block in get_data_hash'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:242:in `each_line'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:242:in `get_data_hash'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_table_to_my_object_time_converter_service.rb:21:in `get_my_object_times'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/text_processor_service.rb:33:in `process_page_data'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/demoapp/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:82:in `process_my_object_data'
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

Comment: Can you give a specific value of `phrase` that triggers this behaviour? Also, `ASCII-8BIT` is not meant to hold text, but pure byte-level data; what encoding are you actually using in the content of `phrase`? The solution should be to force the encoding of `phrase` to the actual encoding, then encode into UTF-8, then apply the regexp. (I believe the regular expression containing `\p{Space}` will be UTF-8. `/foo/.encoding` is not UTF-8 on my machine.)

Comment: WHen I ran 'puts "#{phrase.encoding}", the output was "ASCII-8BIT" so althoughh you say "ASCII-8BIT" is not meant to hold text, that is the reality in my example.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this with random ASCII-8BIT data in both 2.3.0 and 2.3.1, to no avail.  Knowing the contents of `phrase` would be very helpful.

Comment: I am saying "not meant to hold text" with a reason. It *can*, obviously, but if it does, it is almost always a programmer error. ASCII-8BIT is actually "null encoding", it says "I got these bytes but I don't know what they mean". For example, the ASCII-8BIT string `"\xc3\xa4"` is `"ä"` when forced to UTF-8, but `"Ã¤"` in ISO-8859-1, `"ﾃ､"` in SJIS... You will probably not get any errors as long as you stick to lower half of ASCII, as most encodings are the same up to there, but once you engage that 8th bit, the regexp will need to know the exact encoding before it can know what a "Space" is.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose we have a similar problem; putting it in simplest terms:

```
str = "Some text\xC2\xA0followed by more text."
enc = str.encoding 

#  returns ==> #<Encoding:Windows-1252>

# here is my initial attempt, which failed:
matches = str.match(/\xC2\xA0/)
# returns ==> Encoding::CompatibilityError 
# (incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with Windows-1252 string))

# here is my second attempt:
newstr = str.encode('UTF_8', 'Windows_1252', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: ' ')

# returns ==> Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError (code converter not found (Windows_1252 to UTF_8))

# here is my third attempt:
matches = str.match('\xC2\xA0'.encode(Encoding::Windows_1252))

# returns ==> #<MatchData "\xC2\xA0">

# here is my 4th attempt: 
matches = str.match('(.*)\xC2\xA0(.*)'.encode(Encoding::Windows_1252))
newstr = matches[1] + ' ' + matches[2]

# returns ==> "Some text followed by more text."
```

Hopefully, that helps.  Only 2 years late...