# Ruby - Incompatible encoding regexp match

Tags: ruby, regex

I developed and automated deployment script for Ruby. However, when I try to run it I stumble upon this error:

deploy.rb:86:in `gsub': incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with CP850 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError).

The line of code it refers to is:

```
      new_content = new_content.gsub(/£ {{(.*)}}/) { |match| "{{"+match.tr('£ {{}}', '')+"}} €" }
```

Any ideas on what is causing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: See [Ruby Regex Error: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9857493/3832970), does it help?

Comment: You source (and hence the regex) is UTF-8 encoded but `new_content` is Windows CP850. Where does `new_content` come from?

Comment: What is `new_content`? Can you provide a [mcve]? How can I **reproduce** your problem?